# PHP script can't open a file when called from a perl script

Tags: php, perl

I have an interesting situation where I have a perl watcher script (using Linux::Inotify2) watch for files to be dropped in a certain directory, then hand them off to a PHP script for processing.  The watched directory and the files in it are not owned by the user the watcher script is running under, but the entire directory tree the files are being dumped in are rwxr-xr-x and the file is world readable.

Here's my delemma.  The PHP script cannot open a file handle on the file passed to it when called from the perl script using system(), exec() or ``.  However, the PHP script *can* open a file handle on the *same* file when the script is run manually from the command-line using the same effective user.

Anyone have any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Are you passing the handle or the file name?  Not clear from the question.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: I get no errors, the PHP sub-shell returns without error. As mentioned in my comment to the answer below, the PHP script can see that the file exists, but silently fails to open a file handle on it.  Again, running the PHP script from the command line as such:

/usr/bin/php script.php filename

works fine, and the script can open a handle on the file 'filename'.  However doing the same in the perl script as:

system("/usr/bin/php script.php filename") causes the PHP script to not be able to open a handle on the file 'filename'.

Comment: So, in answer to my own question it appears to be a race condition, where perl is firing off the system call before the file has completed it's transfer into the directory, as opposed to a problem with the system call itself.  Note to users using Linux::Inotify2 and IN_CREATE, you need to add a sleep statement when checking for events to allow the file transfer / copy to finish before attempting to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your fopen() calls probably rely on relative paths that break when the working directory change.

Comment: I'm passing the file name, and the absolute path is pre-pended within the PHP file.  The PHP file can accurately determine that the passed file *exists* but can't open a file-handle on it.